# Detecting SSH Version Scan using Snort

Tags: security, snort

Is there a rule on Snort to detect a SSH Version scan made on port 22 ?

`scan can be done either using "nmap -p 22 -sV 192.168.1.1"`
OR
on Kali using msf `auxiliary(ssh_version)`

Answer (score 0):

2 types of rules can be used.

`alert tcp any any -> any 22 (content:"SSH-2.0"; nocase; depth:7;)`

`alert tcp any 22 -> any any (content:"SSH-2.0"; nocase; depth:7;)`

[image]

[image]

Do you want traffic of ssh scan?

[image]

This is response traffic of ssh scan. And next rule can detect if the string pattern 'SSH-' occurs 10 times in 2 seconds.

`alert tcp any 22 -> any any (content:"SSH-"; nocase; depth:4; threshold:type threshold,track by_src,count10,seconds 2;)`

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mr.kang  
I believe your rule would raised an alert when ever someone connected to the SSH server and there client included SSH-2.0 in the packet. I don't see how this would help in detecting someone scanning the SSH server to find what version its running.